# AppleScript choosing from list object type of selection

Tags: applescript

It's been a long time since I touched AppleScript and so this might be me just not doing things right. I have a list that I create by collecting the second to the last text item in a path. The path would look something like this:

> HD:Users:xxxxxxxx:Library:Developer:Xcode:Archives:2017-06-14:focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive:"

and so the list is populated with strings that look something like this:

> focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive

I then present to the user and ask them to select an archive. I have another list that contains all the archive paths. What I am looking to do is take the selected archive, find out it's index in the archive name list and then pull the path from the archive path list. Pretty straight forward, at least I thought.  The relevant part of the code looks like this:

```
set myFile to choose from list archiveFileNames with prompt "Select An Archive"
    -->return class of myFile
    
    repeat with i from 1 to count of every item of archiveFileNames
        
        if (myFile is equal to (item i of archiveFileNames as string)) then
            log myFile & "::" & item i of archiveFileNames & "::" & i
        end if
    end repeat
```

I never got a match, even though if I just repeat through the archive name list and use a log statement I can get results that I am looking for:

```
log myFile & "::" & item i of archiveFileNames & "::" & i
```

(See last result for the match)

```
(*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-1-17, 1.40 PM.xcarchive, ::, 1*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-1-17, 10.48 AM.xcarchive, ::, 2*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-1-17, 11.04 AM.xcarchive, ::, 3*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-1-17, 11.24 AM.xcarchive, ::, 4*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-1-17, 9.37 AM.xcarchive, ::, 5*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-3-17, 2.01 PM.xcarchive, ::, 6*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-3-17, 2.02 PM.xcarchive, ::, 7*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-5-17, 2.51 PM.xcarchive, ::, 8*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-12-17, 8.49 AM.xcarchive, ::, 9*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-12-17, 8.53 AM.xcarchive, ::, 10*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 5-16-17, 11.43 AM.xcarchive, ::, 11*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-5-17, 1.42 PM.xcarchive, ::, 12*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-6-17, 10.37 AM.xcarchive, ::, 13*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-6-17, 4.09 PM.xcarchive, ::, 14*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-13-17, 4.01 PM.xcarchive, ::, 15*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-14-17, 11.36 AM.xcarchive, ::, 16*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-14-17, 8.00 AM.xcarchive, ::, 17*)
    (*focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, focus 6-14-17, 8.03 AM.xcarchive, ::, 18*)
```

So I thought this must be a class/type issue where there is no equality because I am comparing apples and oranges. When I run it and have -->return class of myFile uncommented, I get that the class of my selection from the list is a list.

Obviously I am doing something wrong. I was expecting the type to be string, maybe text, not list.

### Edit

OK, so if I change the conditional to this:

```
if (myFile is equal to (item i of archiveFileNames as **list**)) then
```

I get the expected results. But I am still confused as to why the type of an object selected from a list of string is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because `choose from list` returns always a **list** of objects (or boolean `false` if the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd>).

You have to flatten the list.

```
set myFile to choose from list archiveFileNames with prompt "Select An Archive"

if myFile is false then return
set myFile to item 1 of myFile
repeat with i from 1 to count of every item of archiveFileNames
    set currentItem to item i of archiveFileNames
    if myFile = currentItem then
        log myFile & "::" & currentItem & "::" & i
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Has it always been like this, I don't remember having to do that in the past but it's been about 6 years since I've done any hard core AppleScript

Comment: It has always been like this.

Answer (score 2):

try changing the type with the Add-on

```
as text
```

So instead of comparing

```
if A is B
```

which might fail for different classes - do a coercing to text

```
if (A as text) is (B as text)
```

In Addition here's a handler to get an items Position in a list

```
on list_position(this_item, this_list)
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of this_list
     if ((item i of this_list) as text) is (this_item as text) then return i
     end repeat
return 0
end list_position
```

edit: to Clarify your List issue, Please show how you create the list

Comment: Definitely a winner here.